# $R[X] \subset R[X,Y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $R$ is a ring, is true that $R[X] \subset R[X,Y]$ ? I think is true because if we take $f = a_0 + a_1X + \dots a_nX^n \in R[X]$ we can write it as $f = a_0Y^0 + a_1X + \dots a_nX^n \in R[X,Y]$, so $R[X] \subset R[X,Y]$.

Or, another way, we know that $R[X,Y] = R[X][Y]$, so a polynomial from $R[X]$ is a constant from $R[X,Y]$.

Are these valid proofs?

Comment: do you need to write $a_0$ as $a_0Y^0$?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. It is the same argument you use for showing that $R\subseteq R[y]$, only for $R$ replaced by $R[x]$.

Comment: @SineoftheTime not really, because $f$ is viewed as a constant term of $R[X,Y]$ and is already understood

Comment: sure, it's a constant in R

Comment: just consider the inclusion map